# Reactive statement throws an error once it hits undefined variables. How to prevent it?

Tags: undefined, reactive, svelte

just playing around with Svelte. And I have noticed that when the reactive statement ($) is being calculated, it will throw an error when one of the depending variables is undefined.

While this behaviour is correct, how can I prevent it from calculating if the variable it depends on is undefined?

To see the error, type something in either of the fields, and then delete it, so it becomes empty.

```
<script>
    let num = "";
    let secondNum = "";

    $: output = "prefix" + num.toString() + secondNum.toString() + "suffix";

    function handleChange() {
        console.log(num, secondNum);
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    }

</script>
<form on:submit={handleSubmit}>
    <input type="number" bind:value={num} on:change={handleChange}>
    <input type="number" bind:value={secondNum} on:change={handleChange}>
    <button type="submit">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing a numeric input causes its bound value to be `undefined`. `num.toString()` is an error if `num` is undefined (that's a JavaScript thing, not a Svelte thing).

Easiest fix would be this:

```
$: output = `prefix${num || ''}${secondNum || ''}suffix`;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I do believe it is a javascript thing, but because the reactive statements are being calculated when the bound value changes, I am guessing this undefined check is kind of mandatory for the reactivity to work properly?

Comment: Your reactive statement has to work with whatever values its dependencies could have, yeah